# Prevent grub-mkconfig to pull in files from root partition

Tags: boot, grub, grub2, btrfs, manjaro

I recently made the following changes to my USB installation of Manjaro:

- Set the btrfs compression level for all subvolumes to zstd
- rebalance -czstd

I couldn't boot afterwards, because grub cannot read zstd.
So I created a new boot partition, btrfs compress=lzo and recreated everything as needed.

While this works, I get errors on booting grub, because grub-mkconfig adds stuff like "load font from /@/usr/share/grub/font/unicode.blah".

Can grub be configured to copy the files over instead? As said, grub cannot read zstd…

Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GRUB-Btrfs-Zstd-Support, grub should now support zstd-compressed btrfs partitions.
Though it might be a newer version than the one installed on your system.

Comment: Have seen this one before, thanks. But that's why I was looking for another way… Manjaro hasn't got that version yet, it seems.